# Is it possible to bundle our template into one SWC?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, workflow, swc

I am building an application template in FlashDevelop/Flash, to be used as the template for all our future projects. In a swc-free world, the template has a bunch of library symbols and a whole package of classes in the /lib/ folder that run the whole thing.

What I would like to do, is package all that up into a single swc, so the team can checkout the latest build of the swc from svn at the start of a project, put it in the /lib/ folder and forget about it.

However, all attempts to do this have failed so far. Is it even possible to put everything into one swc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mxmlc -include-libraries C:\libs\as3corelib.swc C:\libs\as3swf.swc -output C:\output\oneSwcToRuleThemAll.swc -load-config "C:\sdk\frameworks\air-config.xml" -- C:\input\EmptyFile.as`

EmptyFile.as :

```
package{
    public class EmptyFile
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not sure for `-load-config "C:\sdk\frameworks\air-config.xml"` but I need it in my projects.

This exemple include "as3corelib.swc" and "as3swf.swc" into one swc named oneSwcToRuleThemAll.swc